# Learning Windows Azure at home?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I want to learn Windows Azure to prepare for MCSD Web Development certification. Assuming that I have access to Visual Studio, VMWare, SQL Server etc., is it possible to develop and test Azure applications locally? I want to run Azure on my virtual machine without registering at Microsoft website, applying for any trial periods etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to locally develop windows azure apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991069/how-to-locally-develop-windows-azure-apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: You *can* learn a lot about Azure without an account. Probably enough to pass the test; but maybe not enough to manage a production deployment.**

You can learn a lot about how applications run inside of Azure using the emulators (express and full) that are included with the Azure tools for Visual Studio. Microsoft has [several](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff687127.aspx) [decent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn339018.aspx) [articles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/) on getting started with the Azure tools. However, there is some tacit knowledge about actually *using* Azure -- things like how to navigate the management portals (or the fact that there currently are *two* portals) -- that can probably only be learned through actually using the infrastructure. Those kinds of questions may not be on the test, but the knowledge will definitely be helpful if you ever have to deal with Azure in a professional context. Start with the emulator, build some things that will run on Azure, and once you have a few samples, reconsider using a 30 day trial to actually run something in Azure and get a "feel" for the real thing.

As a side note, the Azure platform has evolved quite a bit over the last several years... if you find yourself reading an article from 2011 or '12, you may want to check again for newer information, as the recommended tools/APIs/etc may be deprecated or just plain *gone* in the newest SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand Azure without Azure account is to install Windows Azure Pack.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296435.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try  [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/) It's free and if you setup a Microsoft Account you can track your progress. They have a lot of courses on different Microsoft products and I just searched and found a few for [Azure](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Studies/SearchResult.aspx?q=azure).

The good thing I like about the courses is that they are presented by MVP's, MCT's and Microsoft Evangelists, so they know what they are talking about.